# Mongoose range filter using <Model>.find( { dateTimeField : { $gte : startDateTime, $lte : EndDateTime } ) on Date field return nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, datetime, mongoose

I have a model like this:

```
const deviceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   dateTimeStamp : {
      type : Date,
      required : true,
   },
   temp : {
      type : String,
      required : true,
   },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Device', deviceSchema);
```

I have data in this model of every 5 seconds. And lets say I want to calculate average temp, highest temp etc. during a specific range of time, range could be of days, hours or minutes.

**Now the problem is when I filter data on dateTimeStamp, I get nothing.**

---

I have an API like this:

```
app.get("/api/test", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Filtering 1 hour data
    const data = await Device.find({
        dateTimeStamp: {
          $gte: "2023-06-06 17:00:00",  // This string filtering is working in MongoDB Compass
          $lte: "2023-06-06 18:00:00",
        },
      });
    // Data is empty nothing in response

    res.status(200).json({
      totalDocuments: data.length,
      data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    const statusCode = res.statusCode == 200 ? 500 : res.statusCode;
    res.status(statusCode).json({ error: err.message });
  }
});
```

---

I also tried this, still nothing:

```
app.get("/api/test1", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    
    // Filtering 1 hour data
    const data = await Device.find({
        dateTimeStamp: {
          $gte: new Date("2023-06-06 17:00:00"),
          $lte: new Date("2023-06-06 18:00:00"),
        },
      });
   // Data is still empty nothing in response

    res.status(200).json({
      totalDocuments: data.length,
      data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    const statusCode = res.statusCode == 200 ? 500 : res.statusCode;
    res.status(statusCode).json({ error: err.message });
  }
});
```

---

The response I am getting in postman (both API same response):

```
{
    "totalDocuments": 0,
    "data": []
}
```

---

When I console.log the dateTimeStamp

```
const data = await Device.findById("647f6d0957830f245b6e7361");
console.log(data.dateTimeStamp);
// Output: 2023-06-06T11:59:45.000Z
```

---

Sample Document from Compass:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "647f6d0957830f245b6e7361"
  },
  "dateTimeStamp": "2023-06-06 17:29:45",
  "temp": "56.1",
  "__v": 0
}
```

---

express version : 4.18.2
mongoose  version: 7.3.1

I was expecting an array of document ranging from "2023-06-06 17:00:00" to "2023-06-06 18:00:00" according to dateTimeStamp field.

Comment: Is the field called `dt_tracker` or `dateTimeStamp`?

Comment: sorry, I actually renamed every thing to make more sense here and forgot it...they are the same.

Comment: It works fine. https://mongoplayground.net/p/k3BNrEtNw6T. Please confirm you are connecting the right database

Comment: Yes I am connected to right database, confirmed it by fetching documents. I think I found out the cause, the data stored in database is actually String (dateTimeStamp : String), and the type in the schema might had been changed my mistake to date

Comment: @LinDu Is there a way to sort, select the range using dateTimeStamp, which is stored in as string?